# Añadir una nueva Row a una table

Tags: c#, oracle

Mi idea es que mientras se vaya pulsando el botón se vayan añadiendo filas a la tabla

El problema que tengo es que mientras agrego una nueva `row`, siempre se me borra la ultima(la primera) y se me crea una `row` de nuevo, y en total siempre hay una sola `row` que va variando la informacion. Alguna idea?

```
protected void btnPresentar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Este Metodo va bien, Partimos desde aqui


    OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection();
    OracleCommand cmd3;
    OracleDataReader dr4;
    cnn.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE = ######;  USER ID = user; PASSWORD = passwd";
    cnn.Open();
   cmd3= new OracleCommand("Select * from simbolos_ll_desc",cnn);
   dr4 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
    ;

    if (dr4.Read())
    {

        while (dr4.Read()) {
            if (dr4["id"].ToString().Equals(txtBoia.Text) ){
             TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
    TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                img.ImageUrl = buscarImagen(dr4["simb_idSimb"].ToString());
                //Primera de celda de la tabla
                tc1.Text = dr4["Id"].ToString();

                tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
                //Segunda celda de la tabla
                // tabla nueva
                Table t = new Table();
                //fila 1
                 TableRow trp = new TableRow();
                     TableCell tcp = new TableCell();
                     tcp.Text =  separar(dr4["Desc1"].ToString()) ;
                     tcp.ColumnSpan = 2;
                        //  tcp.Width = 200;
                     trp.Cells.Add(tcp);
                //fila 2
                 TableRow trm = new TableRow();
                     TableCell tcm1 = new TableCell();
                     tcm1.Text = separar2(dr4["Desc1"].ToString());
                     TableCell tcm2 = new TableCell();
                  //tcm2.HorizontalAlign= HorizontalAlign.Left;
                     tcm2.Controls.Add(img);
                tcm1.Width = 25;
                       // tcm2.Width = 100;
                       // tcm1.BorderWidth = 1;
                       // tcm2.BorderWidth = 1;
                     trm.Cells.Add(tcm1);
                     trm.Cells.Add(tcm2);
                //Fila 3
                 TableRow tra = new TableRow();
                     TableCell tca = new TableCell();
                     tca.Text =  dr4["desc2"].ToString() ;
                     tra.Cells.Add(tca);
                t.Rows.Add(trp);
                t.Rows.Add(trm);
                t.Rows.Add(tra);
               tc2.Controls.Add(t);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
                tblBoias.Rows.Add(tr);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Buff.. este código es complicado de seguir, pero te voy a dar un consejo. Carga los datos de la base de datos una sola vez (no tiene sentido que acudas a la base de datos con cada pulsación del boton) y almacenalos en un `DataTable`. Añade una variable en la que almacenes cual es el indice de la fila que tienes que mostrar a continuacion. Y luego en cada pulsacion del boton, añade la fila que tienes en el indice y sumale uno a este ultimo.

Comment: Ya he probado con eso ultimo (lo del contador), y aun asi sigue sin funcionar, llevo toda la mañana con esta historia y me estoy tirando de los pelos. en cuando a lo de El DATATABLE lo tendre en cuenta

Comment: @Pikoh el codigo que esta ahi no hace lo que el dice que quiere hacer. Cuando apreta trae todo y no va de a uno. Igual yo tengo mis dudas de si con semejante despliegue de variables no hay algun otro problema por el cual solo se agrega una fila a la tabla. Tiene tablas dentro de celdas dentro de tablas. es raro. Tal vez deberias mostrar tambien que te resulta ahora y que quieres que resulte.. Y hacer una prueba de escritorio con datos basicos antes de ir a la BD

Comment: Por otro lado, esto es una aplicación web entiendo. Debes tener en cuenta que con cada pulsación de boton la pagina realiza un `PostBack`, con lo que es posible que la tabla se elimine completamente al eliminarse la pagina y volver a recrearse...

Comment: @Pikoh ayer lo hacia con un label todo y me salia sin problemas, pero el momento en el que he metido la tabla se ha desmoronado todo. Probare con el DATATABLE  y os comento que tal va la vaina

Comment: De todas maneras, y como otro consejo, usa algun tipo de control habilitado para mostrar datos como un `DataGrid`o algo asi. Todo lo demás es complicarte la vida :)

Comment: @Geraniego, los consejos de Pikoh y gbianchi son totalmente acertados para el problema que estas planteando, debes de tenerlos en cuenta. Ahora yo te indico otro problema que tienes. Cuando ejecutas la instrucción `if (dr4.Read())` ya estas moviendo el resultado un registro hacia adelante entonces cuando lanzas el `while (dr4.Read())` ya vas a tener un registro menos para mostrar. En resumen esa instrucción `if` te sobra.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, entre ayer y hoy estoy aprendiendo un huevo gracias a vosotros :D

Comment: @Pikoh donde puedo dar a la duda por respondida? que ya he solucionado el problema

Comment: Es este caso, ya que no hay ninguna respuesta, no puedes aceptar nada. En todo caso, añade tu propia respuesta y transcurridas 24h podrás aceptarla.